# Arrays: Passing Index of String Array to Index of Int Array for Output only

Tags: c++, arrays

I am looking to pass the int values of an array to the indices of a string array "behind the scenes." I want the string arrays to be ouput with their strings, however I want to do math on the indices the strings represent.

In other words I would like to combine or blend them together so that I have 4 arrays: 2 of them are int arrays, 1 of the int arrays is for doing math on; and 2 of them are string arrays, both of them are for display to the screen purposes only.

If I try to loop through the int arrays and assign the string array elements to their corresponding indices, it won't compile, and I get the error message:
"Cannot convert 'std::string' to 'int' in assignment."

If I try to loop through the string arrays and assign them the int array values to their corresponding indices, it compiles, however I get the ASCII representation of the int values, rather than the numbers.
Here is the code for looping through the int arrays:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()          
{   

int typeArray[4] = {55,66,77,88};
int valArray[13] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};

string types[4] = {"Manny", "Moe", "Jack", "John" };
string values[13] =    {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten",
                      "Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen"};

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(typeArray)/sizeof(int); i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(valArray)/sizeof(int); j++)
    {

        typeArray[i] = types[0];
        valArray[j] = values[0];
        }
  }

  system("Pause");
  return 0; 
}
```

AGAIN, IT WON'T COMPILE, AND I GET THE ERROR MESSAGE NOTED ABOVE.
Here is the code for looping through the string arrays and the output:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()          
{   

int typeArray[4] = {55,66,77,88};
int valArray[13] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};

string types[4] = {"Manny", "Moe", "Jack", "John" };
string values[13] = {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten",
                      "Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen"};

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(types)/sizeof(int); i++)
     {
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(values)/sizeof(int); j++)
      {

        types[i] = typeArray[0];
        values[j] = valArray[0];

        cout << "This is types array: " << types[i] << "  This is values array: " << values[j] << endl;
      }
   }

  system("Pause");
  return 0;
```

### }

HERE IS THE OUTPUT SHOWING ASCII CONVERSIONS OF THE INTS:

### This is types array: 7 This is values array: ☺

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `typeArray[i] = types[0];`? `typeArray` is an array of ints, and `types[0]` is a string.

Comment: Hi Vlad, I want "types[0]" array to DISPLAY "Manny" but to actually have a value of "typeArray[0]" which is -55-.

Comment: ...or the other way around...?...."typeArray[0]" can maintain its value of -55-, however, it outputs to the screen with the string "Manny".

Comment: Just remove all the assignments and print out the values.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you can't store a `String` in an `int` you can however create a `String` from an `int` this is why the second option compiles.

However when you do this you get the character with the ASCII value equal to the `int`. So in your case you get the ASCII character for `7` which is the character you are printing.

If you want to print the `7` you need to get the ASCII code for `7` you can do this with:

```
types[i] = typeArray[0] + '0';
```

But I don't think this what you actually want to do.

You could create a structure that holds an `int` and a `String` to keep them together, and then make an array of that `struct`.

```
typedef struct typeStruct {
     int value;
     string disp;
} typeStruct;
```

typeStruct types[13];

Edit: based on your comment on this answer I think you want this

```
string values[6] = {"INVALID", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
int size = 6;   
...   

//This prints the value for a given int
void printValue(int val) {
     cout << values[val] << endl;
}

//This gets the int val for a given string
int getValue(string str) {
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(str.compare(values[i]) == 0) {
              return i;
        }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: This is similar to how a deck of cards is made.  While the user sees "Ace," "Jack", etc... the program sees "1" and "10".

Comment: @codechick I think I understand what you want and posted something similar.

Comment: Thank you for that idea, it does work in outputting to the screen.  However, I'm a little unclear how to "check" the actual int value in each element...?

Comment: @codechick if you loop over the array like I did in `getValue` and return the index of the matching string you will get the int value associated with the string.

Comment: Twain, I just added your "getValue" function, and am getting the error: "No matching function for call to strcmp(std::string&, std::string&), candidates are: int strcmp(const char*, const char*)."  ...................I did include <string>.

Comment: @codechick sorry I used strcmp (it's for char * not strings I'll fix it)

Comment: Awesome...(where's my ASCII smiley...; )

Comment: Hi Twain, almost there, however, it won't take "size" as a length.

Comment: @codechick I created a variable size that was equal to the number of elements in the array. if you want to use `std::array<string, 6> values` instead of the array I've defined you can then use `values.size()` to get the size.

Comment: Twain, thank you for the additional info.  I had the string variable "str" initialized to -0- which was jacking me up...; )  I'm rollin' now...Please keep an eye out for my revised double vector version coming up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should use

```
 Map<int, string>
```

It will help you to bind an integer value to the string.
Anyway, you're getting an error because you are trying to assign string to int.

Comment: I agree that a map is more logical.  However, I'm moving toward making a card deck using a vector which I've seen done before.  How does a card display to the screen as an "Ace" yet it is considered a "-1-" by the program?

Comment: If I understand you correct, you should in this case specify two vectors : one for integer values and another for string values. In this case it is possible to bind them through the same vector index.

Comment: Hello denied, thank you for that suggestion.  I actually already have a 2-dimensional vector of ints that consists of 2 int arrays that are loaded into it.  However, if I do the same thing and create a 2-dimensional vector of strings and 2 string arrays and load them into the string vector, how do I bind them through the same vector index?  Should I post my code first?

Comment: For example, you have two indexes 22 and 33 and two strings "one" and "two". And you want to bind 22 to "one" and 33 to "two". so you creating a vectors ints[2] = {22, 33} and strings[2] ={"one", "two"}. So you can create a for loop and for the index i = 0 you will get ints[i]==22 and strings[i]=="one". You see? It's kinda virtual binding. But for every defined i you have a strings[i] value associated to ints[i] value.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I want to do.  Let me get it coded and I'll repost again with title: Two 2-Dimensional Vectors, 1 int and 1 string, bound by index."  Thanks again!